# How to execute a shell script when I activate a particular conda env?

Tags: environment-variables, conda, virtualenv, environment

I want a shell script, say `myscript` (`#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` and it modifies `PATH`, `PYTHONPATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`), to be executed whenever I activate a `conda` env say `xyz`. I placed it inside  `${CONDA_PREFIX}/etc/conda/activate.d/`, it does not work.

I tried to put `source "${CONDA_PREFIX}/etc/conda/activate.d/myscript"` in `${CONDA_PREFIX}/bin/activate` and found that `${CONDA_PREFIX}/bin/activate` is not executed at all, even a simple `echo` statement at the beginning of `${CONDA_PREFIX}/bin/activate` does not show anything when I activate `conda activate xyz`!! What to do?

Note: after activating `xyz` if I `source ${CONDA_PREFIX}/etc/conda/activate.d/myscript` it works fine. Please help.

**More important:**
When I manually `source ${CONDA_PREFIX}/etc/conda/activate.d/myscript`, the cahnges are permanent, so `PYTHONPATH` and others remain modified even if I switch to another env. I wanted that `myscript` only affects within the `xyz`  env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checklist:

`CONDA_PREFIX` in `${CONDA_PREFIX}/etc/conda/activate.d` is an environment to be activated. In your case it's `envs/xyz` in conda root directory.

The files to be sourced must have `.sh` extension. In your case it must be `myscript.sh`

To undo the effects of `activate.d/myscript.sh` you should create `deactivate.d/myscript.sh`. If your `activate.d/myscript.sh` just contains `export _SOME_VAR=value` your `deactivate.d/myscript.sh` should contain `unset _SOME_VAR`

To debug activation run `conda shell.bash activate xyz` — the last line after the list of exports should be `. CONDA_ROOT/envs/xyz/etc/conda/activate.d/myscript.sh`

I just checked this in my mini-forge installation — works as documented.